# Ok to use a C# Panel's HWND in a Win32 Dll on another thread?

Tags: c#, winapi, dll, direct3d, ui-thread

I have something working but I'm not sure it is OK and if it will cause problems later on.

I have a Win32 C++ app which does some video processing and uses Direct3D for display (not my code).  My task is replacing the GUI with a C# GUI.

I've made the C++ code into a dll.
I've created a GUI in C# and have a panel intended for the video-display.  I pass this panel's HWND to the dll, and everything seems to work just fine.

But - that panel is being accessed by a thread other than the one it was created on, which shouldn't be done.
Part of me wants to "leave well enough alone" but this feels wrong and I suspect it will cause problems down the line.  Such as when we  want to catch click-events on the panel, which will be on the main or UI thread ... which created the panel.

ANy suggestions on how I should be doing this?
Thank you
Thanks

Comment: Perhaps have the C++ code create its own HWND that's a child of the Panel (rather than trying to use the Panel HWND directly) - then you can do with that as you please. (If the panel changes size during its lifetime, you may need to have the C# code P/Invoke to C++ to let it know it should resize appropriately - but that's simple enough, can use SetWindowPos across threads.)

Answer (score 2):

I think you already know the answer to this. Windows have thread affinity. All operations on a window should be performed from the thread that created it.

Given this rule, I can't imagine that the DLL is responsible for moving window access onto a different thread and presume it is your code that does it. The solution is for you to create and access the window in the same thread that calls the DLL.

Comment: There are large amounts of data on the C++ side, for the video processing - so I'd rather not bring that to the C# side.  To do this on the C++ side, is there an equivalent to component.InvokeRequired and then an Invoke?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem I've seen with this technique is that your UI can flicker.  If you are early enough in the process to use WPF you may want to take a look at [D3DImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.d3dimage.aspx) if not what you are doing now will mostly work.

Comment: I'm not redoing the video processing which has been functional for years.  Note that it violates the "dont access a window from another thread" rule in the pure C++ version.  
THat part is staying in the DLL